# Headless CMS for BOT

Tags: botframework, bots, headless-cms

I have the related messages like a dependency tree. And I want to store and update messages layout in some website. But i wan't to develop website. I was adwised to search in headless cms systems.

Maybe someone know headless cms system for tasks like this? Or someone know better solutions?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you are expecting with BOT ? Whether BOT is acting like CMS or etc.

Comment: It's bot for finding gifts. So for the first, user select "Find gift". For second, select some categories (like "for male", " for female", "for childs", "for hobby", "for work" and e.t.c). In the end bot receomend the gift. And i want to store all this messages and them sequance in website for changing.

Comment: And all of this messages will be set in advance and sometime will be changed. So no needed AI.

Comment: If you are really looking for Microsoft bot implementation then I can give one suggestion of your question. Each turn information you can store in azure app service with the help of application insight telemetry client and the Id you can consider as conversation id. obviously, you need to store user information like email Id or userId for the correlation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at Firebase or Supabase. If you want to update messages from the UI, then you will encounter some limits with a headless CMS.

[Here](https://medium.com/android-news/building-chatbot-with-firebase-and-api-ai-5b787fe693a9) is an example for building a chatbot with firebase.